# Cannot import name 'get_cloud_client' from 'gretel_client'

Tags: python, syntax-error, importerror

I keep getting the error

```
Cannot import name 'get_cloud_client' from 'gretel_client'
```

when I import using

```
from gretel_client import get_cloud_client

client = get_cloud_client(prefix="api", api_key="prompt")
client.install_packages()
```

I have followed all documentation and tutorials which say to just install using

```
!pip install -U gretel-client
```

and I have checked that the package exists using

```
!pip freeze
```

However it still cannot load it. Does anyone know why?

This is the only package I am having trouble with loading, everything else is fine.

Comment: At least provide us with the import line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is the older way of using *gretel_client*.

You have two options, either to install and use an older version of the library:
`pip install gretel-client==0.7.13`

Or learn how to use the latest version of the library, the docs might be helpful:
https://python.docs.gretel.ai/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks, thats stopped the import error but now it gives the error "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'install_packages'"

Comment: @hanyingchan I modified my answer, I think you are looking for 7.13.0 version.

Comment: It appears the newest version 0.15.2 doesn't allow the import, and version 0.5.1 is not allowing the 'install_packages'

Comment: @hanyingchan correct, however, version 0.7.13 seems to work fine, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, 0.7.13 works now thanks very much, although I now get a 'GretelInstallError: Could not fetch package details from endpoint.;' which is coming from the line: 'client.install_packages()' I literally just copied in my API key when prompted to so Im not so sure why. I have seen the API key work on a different code example but its not working here